# Saturation current of Common Mode Choke

Tags: dc-motor, inductor, saturation, common-mode-choke

I am currently designing a driver for a brushed DC-Motor.
The motor is driven by a full bridge (PWM) that switches at about 20kHz.

For our application, it is required to increase the inductance of the motor by an external inductor that is connected in series to the motor. The added inductance should be about 1.5mH. The expected peak current is 4A.

When searching for a specific inductor with these specs, all I can find are common mode chokes. They appear to have large inductance and are also rated for high currents. However, I have never used a common mode choke and honestly, I doubt that it is suited for this kind of application.

What makes me susceptible is, that none of the datasheets I've looked into has rated a saturation current (which is usually one of the first things I look at for normal inductors). Also, I don't know how it should be connected in my circuit.

[image: Common-Mode-Choke]

Option1: Bridge A -> 1-2 -> 3-4 -> DC-Motor -> Bridge B
Option2: Bridge A -> 1-2 -> DC-Motor -> 3-4 -> Bridge B
Option3: Bridge A -> (1-2 and 3-4 in parallel) -> DC-Motor -> Bridge B

Can anyone give me advice? Is there a typical saturation current for Common Mode Chokes?

Comment: 1.5 mH is a lot of inductance at 4 A; are you sure about that? Common-mode chokes are going to have very low saturation currents, since they're not designed to be used with large common-mode currents on them, and differential-mode currents cancel out (that's the whole point of a common-mode choke).

Comment: CMCs typically saturate in the 10-50mA range. You need to shop for "inductors", which will have saturation ratings. Note that the motor itself will have on the order of ~mH internally; why they ask for additional inductance is not apparent. Option 2 is preferred for EMI reasons if nothing else, and you can use half and half as individual inductors.

Comment: The necessity of another huge inductor strikes me as odd. I am interested why this would be required